# Files not created inside any directory, It's creating only in /root

Tags: git, dockerfile, python-3.6, ubuntu-18.04, yocto

I'm working on dockerfile and i'm new to this. In dockerfile top we taken client base image and we are executing the commands. We created one directory , now we enter into this new dir . we are executing the commands , Please check the below data this is repo file

## git-1.7 is in (EOL) Ubuntu Precise.

MIN_GIT_VERSION = (1, 7, 2)      # minimum supported git version

repodir = '.repo'                # name of repo's private directory

S_repo = 'repo'                  # special repo repository

S_manifests = 'manifests'        # special manifest repository

REPO_MAIN = S_repo + '/main.py'  # main script

GITC_CONFIG_FILE = '/gitc/.config'

GITC_FS_ROOT_DIR = '/gitc/manifest-rw/'

In general ubuntu machine when i execute the commands it's creating like this Newdir/.repo/reo/*
But when i run same commandinside  client base image or inside cotainer it's creating /.repo/repo/root/.repoconfig
the difference is .repo/repo/ is creating before /root inside client container. Normal ubuntu container it's creating inside our own dir..

can any one please help on this is there any thing overide the paths in client base image

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with anything you've listed *except* docker, and it's probably due to your docker mounts.

Comment: How we can change the client base image or container to all the customized . Base image already git 2.17 and python 3.6 installed and we are not able to upgrade 2.2 or 2.3 git version In this container

Comment: Without a lot more information, I can't answer that. But the dockerfile (or docker command) will say what paths get mounted where in the image and this will control where the files land relative to the host OS.